# How to see why Outlook calendar items from one machine stopped synchronizing to server?

Tags: ms-office, calendar

I'm using macOS 10.14 Mojave, with Microsoft Outlook client synchronizing with a server. It worked fine for a long time (years).

All of a sudden, I noticed that while I can see the calendar and new items (created on other machines that sync to my account) perfectly (i.e., it's clearly synchronizing), new appointments made on this machine do not appear on the Outlook Web Access view of the calendar, or on any other machines that also synchronize to it. They stay local and never go up to the server. I see no errors reported.

One other piece of data:  calendar appointments whose time or body text is edited on my client - those updates DO show up on the server. So it's clearly able to sync changes up, but brand new appointments made on this client do not show up on the server.

How do I debug this?  Is there a way for someone (whether me or a Microsoft tech) to track down why specific calendar items that exist of my client do not go up to the server?

I was making new appointments for days before I realized they weren't synchronizing, so I'd even like to get a list of these (in case I end up nuking my client and starting from scratch, since they will get lost and I'll need to re-make them, although I have no guarantee that will fix it).

Comment: My first troubleshooting step with Outlook sync issues is to remove the account in question and re-add it. That fixes an unfortunately large number of problems. And as all mail, calendars, etc are kept on the Exchange server it should be a quick/easy thing to try.

Comment: Are you using your Mac in an enterprise environment? Could it be that the Exchange server was recently updated to a release that is not fully compatible with your Outlook version? This compatibility matrix may be useful: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/supportability-matrix?view=exchserver-2019#clients

Comment: The problem with re-creating the account is that I will then lose all the local appointments that I've been making for weeks (before I realized they were not syncing up to the server). Is there at least a way to get a list of those somehow?

Comment: I don't think it's a server release issue because I tried it with an even older machine (10.13) and it works fine to sync upwards.

Comment: So, although unlikely, it could still be a compatibility issue... What version of Outlook do you use? What is the Exchange server version? If you using your Mac in an enterprise environment, have you contacted IT support? Instead of removing your account and re-adding it, could you create a new user on your Mac, set up Outlook, test if appointments get synced and report back?

Comment: Outlook is 16.54 (21101001). I'm not sure what the server version is. But I noticed one thing. I have 2 accounts on this server. One works fine, while the other won't sync new appointments up. I've reported it to the IT support but no help so far.